# gcp Assigning exetrnal IP address to node in node pool

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a node pool (created in terraform), and I have a external IP reserved in my project.

I want one of the nodes in the node pool to always be assigned that specific IP address.

Is there a way to do this on GCP?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign [static external](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#IP_assign) IP addresses to the instances, but it is impossible for GKE nodes because nodes are mortal in nature and can get reassigned. Here you need to reserve a static IP address for each node and that's not possible. You might waste the static IP address resources, if the reserved static IP addresses are not used. You still need to pay for that .

Also you have an option to [configure HTTP load balancer using ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) and reserve a static IP address for your Load balancer. Instead of using NodePort you can use ClusterIP type services and create an [ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress) rule forwarding the traffic to those services. By using [Cloud Nat](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview#interaction-routes) you can route the egress traffic through a static IP.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes is based on the idea that your nodes (infrastructure) are disposable and should have no meaning.

Any node can malfunction or just be shut down by the clouder at any time (think about ephemeral instances).

Most people just need to expose some deployment or a pod.

To make life simple (not just for the SRE but for the scheduler software as well), we usually have one pod per node.

I guess you think you need to give a specific address to a node because it has one pod inside that *must* have this address for some reason.

If you need to give a specific IP address for a development, you need to expose it (with `kubectl expose` using the `--external-ip` option).

I believe the only case where you might need to have a fixed IP tied to a node is if you're need to run in that node some software that is licensed for that IP address, but I am not sure about the use case.

Comment: Maybe [Kubevirt](https://kubevirt.io/) might help if you have some software licensed by IP?